# Соответствие дня недели дате из массива

Tags: php

Помогите, пожалуйста, дописать код, чтобы день недели из массива соответствовал дате

```
 $days = array( 1 => 'Понедельник' , 'Вторник' , 'Среда' , 'Четверг' , 'Пятница' , 'Суббота' , 'Воскресенье' );

$today = new \DateTime('+1 day');
    if ($today->format('N') == 6) {
      $tomorrow = $today->modify('+2 day');
      echo $tomorrow->format($days[date( 'N' )] .' d.m');
    } elseif ($today->format('N') == 7) {
      $today->modify('+1 day');
      echo $today->format($days[date( 'N' )] .' d.m');
    }
     elseif ($today->format('N') == 5) {
      $today->modify('+3 day');
      echo $today->format($days[date( 'N' )] .' d.m');
    }
    else {
      echo $today->format($days[date( 'N' )] .' d.m');

    }
```

Сейчас выводится так (должна быть среда): [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: **Комментарии были [перемещены в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/151865/discussion-on-question-by-------); пожалуйста, не продолжайте дискуссию здесь.** Прежде чем разместить комментарий ниже этого, пожалуйста, ознакомьтесь с [назначением комментариев](/help/privileges/comment). Комментарии, которые не запрашивают уточнения или не предлагают улучшения, скорее всего должны быть [ответами](/help/how-to-answer), размещены на [meta] или написаны в [chat]. Комментарии, продолжающие дискуссию, могут быть удалены.

Answer (score 0):

Если я правильно вас понял:

```
$days = ['Понедельник' , 'Вторник' , 'Среда' , 'Четверг' , 'Пятница' , 'Суббота' , 'Воскресенье'];

$today = new DateTime();

foreach($days as $key => $day){
    if(($today->format('N') - 1) === $key){
        echo $today->format($day .' d.m');
    }
}
```

Если надо не текущий день, то вместо

> Datetime()

, используйте DateTime с нужной датой